# <img src="*.svg"> to inline SVG for CSS editing

Tags: css, html, node.js, svg

What I would like to do, is having `<img src="some.svg">`, because inline svg can be really pain while in the html and it can be downloaded in parallel, but use the **CSS** to edit things like `fill:#fff`.

PS.: The webpage is going to be on a nodeJS server and the page itself is basically static. (Modified via Ajax)

Comment: Don't see any question.  You could use SVG images in `img` tag.

Comment: But i can't style them with CSS later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're trying to use your css code from your html file or stylesheets and apply them to elements within a separate svg file, i.e. set the fill or stroke color.

It seems that css rules from your html file (either in script tags or from linked stylesheets) do not affect svg elements if they are included via an image tag.
I thought that you could use an external style sheet within the svg file, which technically you can (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Fills_and_Strokes), but when I tried that with both Chrome and Firefox, I got mixed results.  Specifically, the external style sheet worked if I loaded the .svg file in the browser (i.e. put the path to the .svg file in the url bar) but if I included it via an img tag, then the external style sheet had no effect.  I don't know if that's a bug, a feature, or something I did wrong somewhere.

Maybe I missed something, but based on my attempts, you can only reliably use css outside of the svg if the svg is embedded.  Maybe you can try to include the svg elements as html snippets or something like that?

EDIT:

Apparently it's a feature - https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=628747

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it won't solve the problem. I would like to use things as `parent:hover` etc.

Comment: You might try searching Google for "Html5 Imports" and see if there are some solutions down that road.

Comment: Just for sake of what it worse, img elements can't load other external resources declared in the media it does load (no external `<image>`, `<script>` nor  `<?xml-stylesheet>`)